# Tell Ember to rerender component

Tags: ember.js, discourse

I've defined a component as follows:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNameBindings: ['isCategory'],

  didInsertElement: function() {
    Ember.addObserver(Discourse, 'currentPath', this.routeChanged);
  },

  routeChanged: function(){
    var route = Discourse.get('currentPath');

    if (route == 'discovery.top') {
      this.set('path', '/top');
      this.set('label', 'top');
    } else if (route == 'discovery.categories'){
      this.set('path', '/categories');
      this.set('label', 'Categories');
    } else {
      this.set('path', '/latest');
      this.set('label', 'Latest');
    }
  },

  render: function(buffer) {
    this.routeChanged();
    buffer.push('<a href="' + this.get('path') + '">' + this.get('label') + '</a>');
  }
});
```

The logic (while not pretty) works as intended, however I don't know how to tell Ember to rerender the component when the value of `path` or `label` changes - I've tried using `.observes()` on the render function, as well as trying to call `this.rerender()` but this doesn't work.

Thanks

Edit:

Yes, of course I should not be manually rendering.

I now have a simple template:

```
<a href="{{path}}">{{label}}</a>
```

Backed by this component:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNameBindings: ['isCategory'],
  templateName: "components/memory-nav",

  didInsertElement: function() {
    Ember.addObserver(Discourse, 'currentPath', this.routeChanged);
  }.on('init'),

  routeChanged: function(){
    var route = Discourse.get('currentPath');

    if (route == 'discovery.top') {
      Ember.Logger.log("Top");
      this.set('path', '/top');
      this.set('label', 'Top');
    } else if (route == 'discovery.categories'){
      Ember.Logger.log("Cateogries");
      this.set('path', '/categories');
      this.set('label', 'Categories');
    } else {
      Ember.Logger.log("Latest");
      this.set('path', '/latest');
      this.set('label', 'Latest');
    }
  }.on('init')
});
```

This now works, and the logs are being called correctly when the path changes. I would have thought that calling `.set` on the object would update the template automatically however this is not being updated at the moment. What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you need to re-render the whole component instead of just the parts that change? That's the whole point of Ember's two way bindings.

Comment: I have the same question as David. When you say rendering only the parts that matter you mean sub-components? Any way how would he do this? Dont really get the two way data binding here if im forced to observe and calling re-render